# Django static tag adding queryparams to generated static files when using DigitalOcean spaces

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean, bucket

So, my webpage generates file that includes the access tokens when using the static tag in django to link to my static files, preferably i would like this link to go to my server, aka:

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx/static/css/main.css

Right now its generating:

> https://******.digitaloceanspaces.com/fpl/static/css/main.css?AWSAccessKeyId=***&Signature=***%3D&Expires=1571503012

in my html

My settings for static files in production:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '***' 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '****' 
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME= '***' 
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://*****.digitaloceanspaces.com' AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400', } AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATIC_URL = 'http://***.***.***' 
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

How can i change the settings to make it link to my servers nginx instead?

Comment: But why are you setting all of that if your files are on the server and served by nginx? Those settings are for keeping them in s3.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want the files to be served via nginx, but stored on spaces...

Comment: Well this is not a thing that makes sense. It the files are on S3 then that is where they are served from.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay, but Im still unsure why the generated html contains queryparams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, you can disable the generation of queryparams by using the

```
    AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

param in your settings.py